# Fast checking that a system of polynomial equations is satisfiable over $\mathbb{F}_2$

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, boolean-algebras, sat, specific-calculation

I have a (fairly large) system of polynomial equations, of the form
$$
c_1d_1=0,\ c_1d_2+c_2d_1=0,\ldots
$$
(In case it is relevant, all the polynomials are homogeneous of degree 2, except for exactly one which is of the form "homogeneous poly of degree 2"=1.)  I need to check if the system is satisfiable over $\mathbb{F}_2$.  When it is, I'd also like to find one satisfying solution.

I've tried using Mathematica's built-in "Reduce" and "FindInstance" functions, but they time out.  My system can be translated into an SAT problem, which should be tractable.  So, my questions are the following:

Are SAT systems the right way to go?  If so, which one should I use (and how do I transfer my system from Mathematica to the SAT solver?)  If not, what is a better option?

Comment: Recent versions of Maple include a SAT solver based on MiniSAT.  And it also has a translator from Mathematica (I don't know, however, whether your Mathematica data are in a format that translates directly to the correct format for Maple's Satisfy comand).

Comment: Is your system small enough that [either libFES or the crossbred algorithm implemented by Charles Bouillaguet](https://lip6.fr/Charles.Bouillaguet/implementation.html) can handle it?

Comment: @j.p. No idea.  I'm planning to work with hundreds of polynomials in hundreds of variables.  I don't expect this is too big for most systems.

Comment: It turns out that Mathematica has a satisfiability solver "SatisfiableQ" which works well for the problem.